# Reading method values at runtime using reflection (+hack)?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

*Brief:*

We have a C# method which accept parameters.

inside of that method we need to add Sql parameters (according to the *method* parameters).

It  actually looks like this : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP1y2.jpg (to enlarge)
[image]

**Please notice**

I can write a class which will have all the method arguments. But then , I will have to create a class container for each SP ( and we have a lot).

Ok lets continue.

I was thinking to myself : "**WHY** should I [insert each param manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748677%28v=pandp.31%29.aspx) - If I already have its : `name` , `type` , `value` in the method param ? I don't want to do this , maybe reflection will do this for me"  ( *lets leave for now the conversion for `int <->DbType.Int32`*)

But I encountered a problem. it is **not** possible reading values using reflection.

However  , I **did** managed to read values via reflection with a hack.

1) I did this example:  ( simulation to the real scenario)

```
public static void MyMethod(int AddressId, string countryId, DateTime dt) //these are the arguments which need to be attached later
{

 MethodBase mi = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
 var hack = new {AddressId, countryId, dt}; //this is the HACK


var lstArguments = mi.GetParameters()  //get the parameter  name and types
                    .Select(p => new {
                                 name = p.Name  , type=p.GetType().Name
                                 }).ToList();


List < dynamic > lstParamValues= new List < dynamic > ();

foreach(PropertyInfo pi in hack.GetType().GetProperties())  //get the value(!!!) of each param 
{

       lstParamValues.Add(pi.GetValue(hack, null));
}


  dynamic dyn= myDBInstance; // get dynamic reference to the DB class instance ( 

for(int i = 0; i < lstArguments .Count; i++) //dynamically Invoke the method with param name+value.
{
    dyn.AddInParameter(lstArguments [i].name, ((lstParamValues[i] is int) ? DbType.Int32 : DbType.String), lstParamValues[i]);
}

}
```

And  there is the **DB class** ( to **simulate** the `AddInParameter` to see if im getting values)

```
class myDB
{
    public void AddInParameter(string name, DbType dbt, object val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name=" + name + "    " + "DbType=" + dbt + "    " + "object val=" + val);
    }
}
```

**And it is working :**

I executed the method with :

```
MyMethod(1, "2", DateTime.Now);
```

And the output was :

```
name=AddressId    DbType=Int32    object val=1
name=countryId    DbType=String    object val=2
name=dt    DbType=String    object val=05/02/2013 19:09:32
```

All fine.

**the C# Question**

How can I get over this hack :

```
 var hack = new {AddressId, countryId, dt};  //  the method arguments names
```

In my sample I wrote it hard coded.

The reflection method `GetValue` is working only because of this line.

Is there anything I can do to add on run-time the method arguments name as  a property  , so I will be able to do :

```
 foreach(PropertyInfo pi in SOMETHING.GetType().GetProperties()) 
   {
   }
```

Please consider this question as a c# question and not ORM question.

Also , If you want to play with running sample code ( just paste in console proj) : http://jsbin.com/azicut/1/edit

Comment: OMG!! Why do your methods recieve 30+ parameters instead of creating a simple class with those properties and have your methods recieve an instance of the class? then you could do the `SOMETHING.GetType().GetProperties())` replacing Something by your class name

Comment: @HighCore This is not the question. but If you asked - Not every SP param is defined with class ( well not in my job anyway). I agree it would be the correct way. but currently this is the situation. my question is pure C# question. Thanks for replying. :-) And currently My boss dont want to apply an ORM. ( we are using MS enterprise library).

Comment: Don't bother with obscure reflection, *generate* the DAL class if you really need to have such stupid and simple solution.

Comment: @OndrejTucny **even If I will write a class which has all those parameters** ,** I still need to do** `.AddInParameter(...)` for every param. this is what im trying to spare !

Comment: FYI it looks like you've got a bug because you are mapping `apartment` to `@Pob` and `@PersonName` parameters.

Comment: you redefine lstArguments from an anonymous type holding name/type pairs to a list of values from the hack, did you mean that..? Also, where are you getting the parameter values from when not hacked (since I see that hacked values are passed in as parameters), I can't see that you do it in the code provided

Comment: @Dead.Rabit edited.(wrong paste). thanks.

Comment: `And currently My boss dont want to apply an ORM`. Is there a reason why?

Comment: @HighCore  I think I will merge both solutions of your and mine. I will create a class and iterate its properties. (p.s. your last comment is totaly unrelated ).

Comment: @RoyiNamir Keep in mind that doing reflection stuff over many properties is going to be slow.

Comment: @HighCore if you only knew how much code is running with reflection without even you notice.....:-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir An ORM and a good software architecture and design is always preferable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this provide some relief?

Do this once (in the DAL ctor):

```
SqlParameter sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnceParam = sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnce.Parameters.Add("@sID", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnceParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
SqlParameter sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnceParam2 = sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnce.Parameters.Add("@sIDpar", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnceParam2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

Then in the call:

```
sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnceParam.Value = wdc.sID;
sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnceParam2.Value = wdc.sIDpar;                                    
sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnce.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callbackFTSindexWordOnce, sqlCmdFTSindexWordOnce);
```

Better performance than adding the parameter for each call.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. you are invoking executeNonquery after each loop iteration ? I have a bunch of params to insert BEFORE I invoke the method... thanks for reply.

Comment: The syntax work for multiple parameters.  What don't your understand?

Answer (score 0):

`AddWithValue` at least  will save you from writing type name.

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@demographics", demoXml);
```

But also you really shouln't pass that much parameter to a function. A simple [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) class can make your code much more readable. If I am not mistaken you are looking something like pyhton's `locals` ([Need something like locals in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504118/need-something-like-locals-in-python)) which gives you local variables of function as key-value pair and you can't do this in c# as far as i know.

or you simple do not pass all variables you just can pass a `Dictionary<string,object>` and add key values to SqlParameter

Comment: But I will not be able to see with dictionary, the parameteres on compile time. only in run time.it is better to see what you actually send to the sp.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Can you post an example code how you really want to call this procedure? I am really confused here to understand what  you are trying to achieve.

Comment: paste this on console. http://jsbin.com/azicut/1/edit ( this link is in the question)

Comment: @RoyiNamir What about ExpandoObject accepting named arguments?

Answer (score -3):

i'm not familiar with the workings of c# and .net, but if this was java, i would say:

store the current parameters into an arraylist or map

you could either have 3 arraylists, one for each of the parameters that go into the addInParameters method call, or a map with all the values included in it (the type parameter would need to have some duplication as it does now)

use the array list as the only parameter in the insert/update methods
use a for loop so that the AddInParameter call is only written once, and the parameters are like (array1[0], array2[0], array3[0]) rather than the actual values.

in php you could use associative arrays, does .net have associative arrays?